# Adding specific lib to flatpak runtime

Tags: libraries, plugins, flatpak, obs-studio

I'm using OBS Studio installed using Flatpak. One of my installed plugins requires additional library installed on system. Can I make that Flatpak sees this specific lib file somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but using Arch.
I think the path will be very similar:

`/var/lib/flatpak/app/com.obsproject.Studio/x86_64/stable/active/files/lib`

When I wanted to run plugin named waveform, that depend on `libfftw3f.so.3` - I just copied it into this folder (I had to use privileged user to do that) and now everything seem to work like I would expect.